# MYSQL - Replace text in specific field in specific product

Tags: mysql, sql, text, replace, field

My table is "products" and it has the following fields:

product_id 
product_name
availability

My products are:

100 | Apple | In Stock

101 | Oranges | In Stock

102 | Pineapple | Out of stock

But now oranges are out of stock so I want to change it's availability from MySQL.

I want from table "products" to select id "101" and replace it's text availability "In Stock" with "Out of stock"

Comment: You doing it wrong, you better store integer value, like 0 and 1 in "is_available" field, and then in your interface just output text "Stock/Out of stock" depending on value.

Comment: Agree with @MyMomSaysIamSpecial. You should have a lookup table for the `In Stock\Out of Stock`. What if someone says `No Stock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update

```
  update products
  set availability = "Out of stock"
  where product_id = 101
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE products
SET availability = 'Out of stock'
WHERE product_name = 'Oranges';
--WHERE product_id = 101;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of accomplishing this but you should check the 2 example's I've left below, aswell as the official documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

```
UPDATE products SET availability = 'Out of stock' WHERE product_name = 'Oranges';

UPDATE products SET availability = 'Out of stock' WHERE product_id = 101;
```